# Ограничение на максимальное число вводимых символов в текстовое поле

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Вот HTML

```
<div class="text_box_2">
    <div class="count_text_box">
        <p data-count-textarea = "tx_1"><span class="countSimbols">0</span>/<span data-count-num = "10">50</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="textarea_wrapp">
        <textarea data-textarea = "tx_1" placeholder="Опишите суть предложения и что входит в стоимость работы"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вот js

```
$("[data-textarea]").on("keydown", function() {
  textareaName = $(this).attr("data-textarea");
  countTextareaBox = $("[data-count-textarea = '"+textareaName+"']");
  maxVal = countTextareaBox.find("[data-count-num]").attr("data-count-num");
  currentVal = $(this).val().length;
  str = $(this).val();
  if(currentVal > maxVal) {
    str.slice(0, -1);
    $(this).val(str);
  }
  countTextareaBox.find(".countSimbols").html(currentVal);
});
```

Вводится больше чем 50 символов. То есть не работает ограничение, а нужно чтобы после 50 символов перестало вводиться. Не могу найти ошибку. Пожалуйста подскажите как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте атрибут maxlength

```
<textarea maxlength="50" rows="5" cols="10"></textarea>
```

В примере maxlength="50", означает 50 символов максимально

Пример с копией Вашего кода: https://jsfiddle.net/3q6Lj5cw/ и измененный: https://jsfiddle.net/j4L6te5a/

На мой взгляд, в данном случае, лучше подойдет keyup event